# Run Ext.js 5 application with Asp.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, extjs, extjs5

I create ExtJs 5 test app with Sencha Cmd on my Asp.NET MVC application in Scripts/Ext folder:

[image]

I have successfully run it with index.html file in Scripts/Ext folder:
[image]

My scripts folder place in localhost:63059/Scripts:

```
localhost:63059/Scripts/Ext/app.js
localhost:63059/Scripts/Ext/bootstrap.js
localhost:63059/Scripts/Ext/bootstrap.json
localhost:63059/Scripts/Ext/app/Application.js
etc...
```

Start page url: localhost:63059/ or localhost:63059/Home/Index/

I add bootstrap.js in my _Layout.cshtml:

```
<script id="microloader" type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/Ext/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

But when I try to run it in my HomeController IndexAction, I have error: 
**localhost:63059/bootstrap.json Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)**

How I can change default web path to generated ext app with Sencha Cmd?

Comment: I suggest that you use ApiController instead of MVC and then let your Extjs app talk with Api. Also, after you build your app it can be in any folder/path on your server. There is no need for Index.html to be retuned by Controller!

Answer (score 0):

Try loading bootstrap as below place your scripts in content folder

```
   <script src="@Url.Content("~/Content/js/libs/bootstrap.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: No, it not works for me. I still have error: http://localhost:63059/bootstrap.json Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found).

Comment: bootstrap.json is in another place (http://localhost:63059/Content/js/Ext/bootstrap.json)

Comment: from what I see you  have not given correct path to js file in src attribute of script

Comment: Ok, I place all scripts in Content/js/libs folder in my ASP.NET MVC Project: http://joxi.ru/qVrweYXH85J82X, http://joxi.ru/JMAjezQHx8762e, but i have error: http://joxi.ru/WL21JWQfgWZQAX